# React Native - Storyboard as launch-screen not calling viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reactjs, react-native

we use a storyboard as our launchscreen. The storyboard has a View Controller. We connect the View Controller with our custom class which is implementing the `viewDidLoad` event. I changed the settings so that xcode take the storyboard as the new launch screen. The storyboard is correctly displayed visually but unfortunately the events won't get called when the app is launching.

```
@implementation LaunchScreenViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // this is not called
}
```

We want to implement a video as the launch-screen (inspired by the following [project](https://github.com/chinsyo/CHXWelcomeViewController) on github). The View Controller is also set as the initial View Controller. Is there a conflict with React Native which prevents the events?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do what you want to do with launchscreen. Launchscreens only purpose is to display text/image before your app is loaded.

However I think there is something you can do:

- place a static image to your launchscreen (first frame of your video for example)
- after your app is loaded, make sure your initial VC loads your video
- play the video and when it ends give user control

Just make sure your video is not too long, because it could be annoying for user experience, but as I said above I believe there is no way to do it with just launchscreen.

Comment: Ok that sound good. But I still have the problem that the events are not fired. What could be here the problem also in regard of react-native

Comment: If you are talking about events like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc. in launchscreen, they won't fire. You have to set your image you want to display in storyboard.